# "Paranormal Activity"! require and import worked async

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm using Typescript in my Node.js project. So generally I'm using `import * as bla from 'bla';`. Our app is served in DigitalOcean and we faced problems in setting up environment variables (tried both ecosystem and .env, none is consistent). Finally we decided to hard code the variables in a `env.js` file and require it at the beginning of `app.ts`. After that here is how my `app.ts` file looks like:

```
require('./env.js');
.
. 
.
import indexRouter from './routes/index';
```

Interestingly enough, variables defined in `env.js` were shown `undefined` in `indexRouter`. So I've done some console.log. And this is what I got:

```
here in route
here in env.js
```

Any idea why `env.js` was not loaded first? How to solve this?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with TypeScript, but does `import './env.js'` not work?

Comment: yes it worked as Fenton suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript you can [import a module for side-effects only](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only). This is normally discouraged, but seems to match your use case of setting some global state...

> Though not recommended practice, some modules set up some global state that can be used by other modules. These modules may not have any exports, or the consumer is not interested in any of their exports. To import these modules, use:

```
import "./env.js";
```